# How to stop look returning None when there is an element that satisfies if condition?

Tags: python, loops, boolean

I am looping through a list of booleans 
my conditions are if the position of the element is > m 
and `if the element = True`

the function will return the position of the element

this is what I've done :

```
panda =[True, True, True, True]

def find_next (l, m): 
    for i in l:  
        if ((l.index(i) > m) and i ==True):
            return l.index(i) 

print(find_next(panda, 2))
```

I expected the output to be 3.

but I got `None`. why?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That code will generate an `IndentationError`. Please [edit] your question and fix it. We can't be expected to guess which errors are relevant and which aren't. The easiest thing to do is to paste your code, then select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l.index(i)` always returns 0 because it's finding the first instance of `True` in your list

As an aside, you don't need to call `l.index` on every loop because you are redundantly searching the list when you should already know what iteration you are on.

```
def find_next(l, m):
    for index, value in enumerate(l):
        if index > m and value:
            return index
```